# How to get column_def value from table SYSIBM.SQLCOLUMNS on DB2 V11.5 Linux using unixODBC - Ruby

Tags: ruby, db2, unixodbc

I install Db2 V11.5 at Ubuntu 18.04. To connect with Ruby, I use `unixODBC`, `ruby-odbc` gem and `IBM CLI/ODBC Driver`. The configurations is as follows:

```sh
# /etc/odbc.ini
[SAMPLES]
Description=DB2 Conn String
Driver=DB2
Database=SAMPLE
Dbalias=SAMPLE
CurrentSchema=MYLIB_NAME

# /etc/odbcinst.ini
[DB2]
Description=DB2 Driver
Driver=/opt/ibm/db2/V11.5/lib64/libdb2.so
FileUsage=1
DontDLClose=1
LongDataCompat=1

# /opt/ibm/db2/V11.5/cfg/db2cli.ini
[SAMPLE]
Database=SAMPLE
DBName=SAMPLE
Protocol=IPC
Hostname=LOCALHOST
Port=0
Uid=db2inst1
Pwd=xxxxxxxx
```

The connecting running well,

```sh
$ isql -v SAMPLE
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL> select substr(column_name, 1,20) as colname, substr(column_def, 1,10) as coldef from sysibm.sqlcolumns where table_name='MYTABLE_NAME' and table_schem='MYLIB_NAME'
+---------------------+-----------+
| COLNAME             | COLDEF    |
+---------------------+-----------+
| AUTHOR_VISIBILITY   | 0         |
| STATUS              | 0         |
| READ_STATUS         | 0         |
| NULLABLE_STATUS     | 0         |
| LANGUAGE            | 0         |
| ILLUSTRATOR_VISIBILI| 0         |
| ID                  | ID        |
| FONT_SIZE           | 0         |
| COVER               | 'hard'    |
| NAME                | ''        |
| FORMAT              | ''        |
+---------------------+-----------+
SQLRowCount returns -1
11 rows fetched
SQL>
```

Unfortunately, when I try to get table column metadata from `SYSIBM.SQLCOLUMNS` in ruby with SQL as follow

```rb
# test.rb
require "odbc"

DB2  = ODBC.connect("SAMPLE", "db2inst1", "xxxxxxxx")

class DB
  def self.connect
    sql_string = <<-SQL
      SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_DEF 
      FROM SYSIBM.SQLCOLUMNS
      WHERE TABLE_NAME='MYTABLE_NAME' AND TABLE_SCHEM='MYLIB_NAME'
    SQL
    stmt = DB2.run(sql_string)
    stmt.fetch_all
  ensure
    stmt.drop
  end
end
```

result in

```sh
$ ./bin/console
irb(main):001:0> DB.connect
/home/yohanes/Projects/db/test.rb:10: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x0000564429b99c0f
ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-linux]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0021 p:---- s:0102 e:000101 CFUNC  :fetch_all
c:0020 p:0023 s:0098 e:000097 METHOD /home/yohanes/Projects/db/test.rb:10
c:0019 p:0010 s:0092 e:000091 EVAL   (irb):1 [FINISH]
c:0018 p:---- s:0089 e:000088 CFUNC  :eval
c:0017 p:0021 s:0081 e:000080 METHOD /home/yohanes/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb/workspace.rb:85
c:0016 p:0056 s:0073 e:000071 METHOD /home/yohanes/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb/context.rb:385
c:0015 p:0020 s:0064 e:000063 BLOCK  /home/yohanes/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb.rb:493
c:0014 p:0025 s:0061 e:000060 METHOD /home/yohanes/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb.rb:647
c:0013 p:0008 s:0055 e:000054 BLOCK  /home/yohanes/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb.rb:490
c:0012 p:0100 s:0050 e:000049 BLOCK  /home/yohanes/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:246 [FINISH]
.
.
.
and many more lines
.
.
7f9663110000-7f9663113000 rw-p 0036f000 08:09 10097722                   /home/yohanes/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/libruby.so.2.6.5
7f9663113000-7f9663124000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9663124000-7f966314b000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 1185563                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
7f9663155000-7f9663175000 rw-s 00000000 00:01 196660                     /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
7f9663175000-7f966332c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9663342000-7f9663349000 r--s 00000000 08:08 267796                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
7f9663349000-7f966334b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f966334b000-7f966334c000 r--p 00027000 08:08 1185563                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
7f966334c000-7f966334d000 rw-p 00028000 08:08 1185563                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
7f966334d000-7f966334e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffebcfea000-7ffebd7e9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffebd7e9000-7ffebd7ec000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffebd7ec000-7ffebd7ed000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 --xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]


[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: https://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Aborted (core dumped)
```

but if I remove the `COLUMN_DEF`, the query works as expected. Previously i guess this is `ruby-odbc` gem bugs. But when I replace the driver with an `easysoft ODBC driver` the query works as expected which means nothing to do with `ruby-odbc` gems. My question is how to get the `column_def` value by using configuration as above. Do I miss any basic odbc keywords configuration on `odbc.ini` or `db2cli.ini`?

Comment: Not directly addressing your specific question, but could use query SYSCAT.COLUMNS as a workaround? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001038.html

Comment: previously i use SYSCAT.COLUMNS, but i try to avoid it since the DEFAULT column use type CLOB (64K). Otherwise, SYSIBM.SQLCOLUMNS COLUMN_DEF use type VARCHAR(n)

Comment: @yohanes Does the query run correctly in isql ?   Does the query run correctly with the db2cli tool ?  When it crashes, can you tell which module owns the line of code that triggers the sigsegv ?

Comment: this is the error https://gist.github.com/yohaneslumentut/1892e528f72c02fc6a65b3358af55639

Comment: this is the unmodified isql https://gist.github.com/yohaneslumentut/2ad1568376defb3e87bb5219549c9144

Comment: So the unmodified query works correctly in isql, suggesting that unixODBC is playing correctly with clidriver in this case.   The query must then also run successfully via db2cli tool. The sigsegv is happening when ruby-odbc is involved, for some reason. I would use gdb to investigate further. You can also take a clitrace , and compare clitrace output between the working case(isql) to the failing case(ruby-odbc) to get more clues.

Comment: nothing to do with 'ruby-odbc'. because when I use easysoft DB2 ODBC instead of IBM CLI/ODBC driver, everything works as expected

Comment: Things are often not what they appear. Debugging required.

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error, finally, I found the answer. Since the `COLUM_DEF` of a column that has no default value contains the null value, so we have to convert null into something else, in this case, I use 'NULL' instead. We can use `NVL` or `COALESCE` for this purpose.

```sql
  SELECT COLUMN_NAME, NVL(COLUMN_DEF, 'NULL') AS COLUMN_DEF
  FROM SYSIBM.SQLCOLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME='MYTABLE_NAME' AND TABLE_SCHEM='MYLIB_NAME'
```